# "Quick Fix" Tyre Repair Spray Cans

Tags: repair, innertube, puncture, sealant

I saw this in my local supermarket, as they are having a cycling event on at the moment. I was thinking this would be quite useful if I had a puncture away from home, the car or bike repair shop, or in case of an emergency, as let's face it, who wants to repair a tyre at night in the pouring rain? I certainly also do not want to ride with a flat tyre, as it can destroy the tire and wheel rim.

This is what I am talking about:

1. What pros and cons are these to these sprays?
2. If I used this, would I be able to repair the puncture, and reuse the inner tube afterwards?
3. Do they actually work? (Implies 1!)
4. It is "temporary", so how far could I cycle before I have any more problems?

Note: I am talking about the sprays in general, not specific brands (e.g in the image)

Edit: Also, I would not want to remove the tyre at all (i.e. so I do not want to carry a spare tube). I am talking about its effectiveness as a "quick fix".

---

Dead link: http://www.baileysbigstore.co.uk/carmotoring/carmotoringpics/cycletyrefix5292.jpg

Possible contenders for "similar product"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks kind of big and heavy. I think I would rather carry a spare tube.  Clearly it is not going to fix any flat.  If you want a clog like fixer then put sealant in your tire like slime.

Comment: I kinda mean as a quick fix solution though, not a long term one (e.g by carrying a new tube). Sorry for not making it clear!

Comment: What part of "If you want a clog like fixer then put sealant in your tire like Slime" was not clear?   Would it not be easier to just Slime your tubes at home rather than waiting for a flat?  Slime is going be lighter than that big can.

Comment: Sorry, but I had no idea what slime actually was. *facepalm*

Comment: I've used the auto tire equivalent a few times and it does work.  Mostly I've used it to repair slow leaks, though -- leaks that standard tire repair places often can't even find.  (My gut feel, though, is that the bike equivalent would be less likely to be effective as punctures are more often fairly massive, and the structure of a bike tire is less suited to this type of sealing.)

Comment: Out of interest, how tall is that can?

Comment: @PeteH - I've seen these cans once or twice, and they're smaller than your average aerosol can.  I'm thinking it's about the size of a pop can.

Comment: These cans are rated for one car tyre/tire.  So may of them are a one-time release valve, not something you can meter out.   The idea is you buy a small/medium/.large can to suit the tyre volume of your car.  Since even a small car tyre is much bigger than a bike tyre, this will either overinflate or you'll have to disconnect the can and waste most of the product,

Comment: Car tyres are intended to run at 30-35 PSI (approximately) so there's a chance this can can't add much more than that - to prevent cack-handed motorists from overinflating their tyre.   So getting to 60-100 PSI may not be possible.

Also, almost all of these products "ruin" the car tyre.  One brand claims their product can be removed for a conventional puncture repair, which is a plug not a patch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pro's:

- May be a quick roadside fix.
- May be able to fix without removing tyre.
- May last a long time.
- May offer protection against a second puncture in the same wheel.

Con's:

- Expensive for a puncture.

  - Bulky and heavy.
  - Only one can per tyre.
  - Wouldn't be suitable for some punctures and would be a waste if you didn't realise this.

This fix may work for a long time, dependent on the sealant and whether it degrades. Silicon sealants do not degrade quickly.

This type of system is good for small punctures where you can quickly identify the cause and eliminate it. If you have a large puncture (such as a tear or a cut) the sealant may not be able to effectively seal it and once the air leaks you would not be able to re-inflate it.

Also it's best practice to ensure you remove the cause of the puncture before inflating a flat tyre. This generally involves removing the tube and checking the tyre so you're not actually saving that much.. If you don't do this you may get a subsequent puncture.

If you are that adverse to fixing a tyre in the rain or at night use a preventative treatment rather than a temporary repair such as this. Use slime tubes (or fill tubes with slime) or move to tubeless and use a sealant such as Stan's. I ride single track twice a week and have put a single scoop of Stan's in each tubeless wheel 6 months ago and have yet had to remove the tyre. I occasionally add air (probably a month ago and this week) so I know I have a leak somewhere but it hasn't required me to fix it yet.

Comment: The need to pump up tyres once a month isn't an indication of losing air through a puncture at all. Air permeates through the rubber, regardless of its thickness. On road bikes with latex inner tubes it's even worse -- some people have to pump before every ride.

Comment: "Wouldn't be suitable for some punctures". This is the key right here. If you have a complete blowout, this isn't going to help.  You won't know it's a blowout unless you take the time to remove the tube and inspect it, and by that time, it's easier just to replace the tube. If you don't inspect it, and it is a blowout, this product would probably cause a huge mess.

Comment: As for last a long time.  The can says temporary.

Answer (score 4):

Slime is lighter and conveniently pre-applied in the convenience of you own own home/garage.
[Slime tube sealant](http://www.slime.com/shop/tube-sealant/)

As for can the tube be repaired?

- The PedalPower can says temporary but not exactly sure what that means.
- As for Sime if it seals a small puncture I just stay with Slime only. If it is a larger puncture it might be too big to repair period. I have tried to patch over Slime but it is hard as if any Slime gets out the glue won't stick.  Yes you need to remove the debris that caused the puncture but if it gets you home then can do it in the convenience of your home/garage.

Comment: Or you can make it even simpler by purchasing pre-filled tubes (I am assuming they are still sold).

Comment: @Aushiker Yep, looks like [prefilled tubes](http://www.slime.com/shop/smart-bike-tubes-presta-valve/) are still sold.

Comment: Does it really help prevent puncture? I think a glass particle, a failed rim, or a broken spoke will cause a puncture anyway. I think Slime helps to reduce normal air leaking.

Comment: @olee22 **Sealant** I don't state it prevents a puncture. Slime does not state it prevents a puncture. It seals a (small) puncture.

Answer (score 1):

***If I used this, would I be able to repair the puncture, and reuse the inner tube afterwards?***

- Main use in bikes: [**tubeless**](http://www.bontrager.com/technology/why_tubeless_ready) systems / [**tubular tyres**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_tyre) (= sew-up). First, must remedy the cause of the puncture: glass, rim, spoke, etc. Sorry, not for inner tubes as you ask!
- Tyre must be rolling to be effective.
- If valve in place application = particles are very small/thin, can help only very small problems.

**Two main types:**

- **Fiber** containing - mechanical plugging of the hole, less efficient, can stay in tube
- **Latex** based (ammonia smell) - hardens, plugs completely, but cures over time, needs to be removed

**The prevent punctures with inner tube tyres:**

- [Puncture proof liners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEcFMnuJzsQ)
- [Puncture proof tyres](http://www.schwalbetires.com/node/943)

**My take:**

- These liquids are great for temporary fixes in cars, when it allows to get to the nearest workshop for repair (and otherwise the car would stay where it is).
- For inner bike tubes, I see no use of it. Anyway the tyre needs to be removed for inspection, and with that effort a new inner tube can be installed.
- When touring, the fastest solution is to carry a spare tyre and inner tube, and switch it right away, and inspect the defective tyre at the next stop.
- I have from the first series of [Schwalbe Marathons](http://www.schwalbe.com/en/tour-reader/marathon-plus.html) on my citybike since 2004, and although it's heavier, I *never* had a flat tyre with that bike ever since. The disadvantage of the Schwalbe puncture proof tyres is the added weight. For touring and citybikes, this is not a concern however.
- The price of inner tubes has dropped significantly, I now install a new inner tube after punctures (vs. repaired tube leaks air, takes time) on my non Schwalbe Marathon bikes. For a very cheap bike, repairing the tube with a [TipTop kit](http://www.rematiptop.com/parts.php?sid=4) is a cheaper/better solution vs. a sealant liquid.

Good article:

[Tubeless Tire Sealant Tech, Part 1 – How Often Should It Be Checked & Replaced?](http://www.bikerumor.com/2014/02/19/tubeless-tire-sealant-tech-part-1-how-often-should-it-be-checked-replaced/)

Comment: I have used Slime successfully on tubes.  Yes you should remove the tire to inspect and remove any debris but if it gets you home it avoids a road repair.

Answer (score 1):

I have used similar products in the past with mixed results. The primary benefit is that is both pump and patch so to speak. But it really doesn't replace a spare tube and portable inflator.

It's mostly good for slow leaks. I used to keep a can in my office and used it for those situations where I came out to the bike rack and found a flat tire. If it works, it works for a reasonably long time. But for most flats it simply doesn't work since the cause of the flat ( nail, glass, wire, etc ) is still in the tire or the size of the hole is simply too large.

It also is relatively low pressure, so it's best for fatish commuting tires. My recollection is that it only works with schrader values. I'm pretty sure I ended up replacing any tube I used it on fairly quickly.